# React-redux get props or state in mapDispatchToProps

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

please excuse potentially noob question, am new to react and react-redux.

I have a component representing a login screen currently. One of its props is "login", a dictionary that contains the email and password. After defining the component, I use the `react-redux` library to connect it with the store like so:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    rootNav: state.rootNav,
    login: state.login,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
  return {
    onLoginClick: () => {
      // TODO: actually get the login credentials from the view
      dispatch(actions.submitLogin('testuser', 'testpw'));
      dispatch(actions.changeRootNav(rootNavs.OVERVIEW_NAV))
    },
    onEmailUpdate: (email) => dispatch(actions.updateEmail(email)),
    onPasswordUpdate: (password) => dispatch(actions.updatePassword(password)),
  };
};
```

Obviously, in the line `dispatch(actions.submitLogin('testuser', 'testpw'));` I want to have the real email and password submitted as a payload with the action. But I don't understand how I should be accessing it from the component (i.e. I can't just use `this.props.login`) or if/how I should be accessing it from the store (where would I pass the store in?)

Any clarification would be extremely helpful!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this can be handled in two ways. mapDispatchToProps is passed as the second argument to the react-redux connect function. It gives the connected component access to certain action creators. In this case you're giving it the action creators `onLoginClick`, `onEmailUpdate`, and `onPAsswordUpdate`.

Those functions are now accessible in your component via `this.props.onLoginClick`, `this.props.onEmailUpdate` etc. An easy solution is to create an `onClick` event on your login button, or `onSubmit` of the login form. If you're updating your Email and Password on your redux state and passing them to this component as props you can do something like this:

In your login class:

```
login() {
  // get password and email from the props
  const pw = this.props.password;
  const email = this.props.email;
  // submit login action with email and password
  this.props.onLoginClick(email, password)
}

render() {
  <form onSubmit={this.login.bind(this)}>
      ...
  </form>  
}
```

And update mapDispatchToProps to have onLoginClick expect an email and password.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
  return {
    // update this action creator to take an email and password
    onLoginClick: (email, password) => {
      // TODO: actually get the login credentials from the view
      dispatch(actions.submitLogin(email, password));
      dispatch(actions.changeRootNav(rootNavs.OVERVIEW_NAV))
    },
    onEmailUpdate: (email) => dispatch(actions.updateEmail(email)),
    onPasswordUpdate: (password) => dispatch(actions.updatePassword(password)),
};
```

**Option 2**

Otherwise according to the react-redux docs here https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md you can also use the second argument of `mapDispatchToProps`, `ownProps`.

So you can change `onLoginClick` to look like this:

```
onLoginClick: () => {
  const email = ownProps.email;
  const password = ownProps.password;

  dispatch(actions.submitLogin(email, password));
  dispatch(actions.changeRootNav(rootNavs.OVERVIEW_NAV))
}
```

and on your form you can do this:

```
render() {
  <form onSubmit={this.props.onLoginClick}>
      ...
  </form>
```

}

or if you want it to be only on a button click...

```
<button onClick={this.props.onLoginClick}>Login</button>
```

Comment: @baisang Glad I could help!

Comment: oops just kidding. option 2 didn't work, but option 1 did. still, thank you. for some reason my ownProps doesn't have login or email/password fields

Comment: `ownProps` is the props passed `into` the connected component, not the props `of` the connected component.